# rails 4: how to link to an conditional ie stylesheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Because of major design flaws in IE9 i want to use a conditional IE statement like

```
<!--[if IE 9]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css" /> <![endif]-->
```

where ie9.css file is in the public folder (it shouldn't be precompiled with the other stylesheets in assets folder).

But it seems that my rails app doesn't use the ie9.css file for IE9.

What am i missing? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with

```
  <!--[if IE 9]
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application-ie", :media => "all" %>
  ![endif]-->
```

in my application layout and put my ie stylesheet in a subfolder /app/assets/stylesheets/ie/ie9.css and load it with a separate manifest:
application-ie.scss

```
/**
 * application-ie.scss
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./ie
 */
```

and in config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.scss application-ie.scss )
```

Answer (score 0):

**html5shiv**

You can use `html5shiv` for conditional IE stylesheet. 
Following gem can adds html5shiv to your rails assets.

```
gem 'html5shiv-js-rails
```

you can refer the gudline here https://docs.omniref.com/ruby/gems/html5shiv-js-rails/3.7.0

Comment: this is for javascript only and doesn't affect my custom IE css stylesheets